# Insert custom CSS class into function?

Tags: php, class, spawn

I want to use my custom CSS style on that code, any ideas how it should be done?

```
        //Load modules
        if ($handle = opendir('modules'))
        {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
            {
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
                {
                    $replace = preg_replace( array ('/(.*?)/', '/[-]/', '/.php/'), array ('$1', '&nbsp;'), $file);
                    $result = ucfirst($replace);
                    echo '<a href="?inav=';
                    echo $replace;
                    echo '">';
                    echo $result;
                    echo '</a><br>';

                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
```

And that I want to insert:

```
<a href="?inav=" class="button101"><span class="user icon">
```

Comment: What's exactly your problem? Echoing the string `class="button101"`?! Or do you want to let PHP generate the CSS class definition for `.button101`? (You should most certainly not do that, but echo `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/stylesheet.css"/>` in `<head>`).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the echo you need:

```
    //Load modules
    if ($handle = opendir('modules'))
    {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
            {
                $replace = preg_replace( array ('/(.*?)/', '/[-]/', '/.php/'), array ('$1', '&nbsp;'), $file);
                $result = ucfirst($replace);
                echo '<a href="?inav=';
                echo $replace;
                echo '"';
                echo ' class="button101"';
                echo '>';
                echo $result;
                echo '</a><br>';

            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
```

Comment: Okay tnx for that but you forget class="user icon" also!